# NSURL is being nulled when I try to set it to an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsurl

I'm using the following code to load some sounds depending on which button a user clicked. The file path is loaded into `testString` perfectly, but when NSLogging `URLToBeReturned`, it comes out as `(null)`. I'm not sure why it's not transferring over.

```objc
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:noteName ofType:@"m4a"]];
NSURL *URLToBeReturned = [NSURL URLWithString:testString];
return URLToBeReturned;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
NSURL *URLToBeReturned = [NSURL URLWithString:testString];
```

use

```
NSURL *URLToBeReturned = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:testString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because it was malformed (from [NSURL reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) as a URL:

> ```
> + (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was malformed, returns nil.

As to a fix (from the same reference):

> URLString
>
> The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808. (To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead.)

So, you can try using `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`